# Search by the mongoose reference field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, reference

I have a payment model as follows.

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({

        payId: Number,
        employeeId: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
            ref: 'employee'
        }],
        desc: String,
        amount: Number,
        date: Date,
    })
```

As you can see the `employeeId` is referenced to a collection called `employee`.
So here I want to search all payments done for employees (Search with `employeeId`).

```
exports.findWithEmpId = (req, res) => {
    const employeeId = req.params.employeeId

     Payment.find({ employeeId: employeeId })
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send(500).send({
                message: err.message
            })
        })
```

But when I Run the above get request it shows only a `[]`.What should I do to make this work

Comment: Can you show example of both documents ( employee & Payment ) ?

Comment: @DhavalDarji You mean employee model and payment model?